# mail from gmail goes to softfail by yahoo with SPF record

Tags: email, spf

I have my own domain, i.e mydomain.com and own email myemail@mydomain.com from which I can send email by php script. I also have custom gmail address (from google apps) myemail@mydomain.com and can login go gmail email panel and can send email from that gmail account.

What usually happens are:
1) I send email (sender: myemail@mydomain.com) from my domain by php script and also send email (sender: myemail@mydomain.com) from gmail (google apps).

2) All email comes to myemail@mydomain.com are received in gmail account, not in domain's webmail.

For this reason, I created the SPF record in Advanced DNS management of my domain as below:

```
v=spf1 mx a:google.com ~all
```

Now when I send email from my domain (by php script using smtp) to anyemail@yahoo.com, I found SPF: pass in header of the sent mail.

But while I send email from gmail account to anyemail@yahoo.com, I found SPF:softfail in header of the sent mail.

What will be the correct syntax of SPF record by which both the email sent will be passed the SPF, sent from my domain and gmail account.

Comment: off topic on stackoverflow. see [google apps documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en) about creating correct spf records

Answer (score 3):

From here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Allowing me to use Gmail to send From: any@mydomain.com with SPF=pass

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to include Google's own SPF record:

```
v=spf1 mx include:gmail.com ~all
```

You are currently using an A-record lookup to the google.com domain, which does not corresponds to IP addresses of their actual SMTP servers.

Comment: Does that mean anybody who uses Gmail can pretend to send from *mydomain.com* without any SPF warnings?